# Use internal static class methods from external dll using c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an assembly A in which code like

```
namespace A{
    internal static class SourceData
    {
        static SourceData()
        {    
            //some code
        }   
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static string getdata(string name)
        {
            return (string) null;
        }
    }
}
```

now I referenced that dll in my project and I want to access getdata() method, Is is possible? and If yes, then how? 
Thanks.

Comment: [The documentation for `internal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) has this very example, showing it is not possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use an interface from an external assembly that's marked as "internal" (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673406/use-an-interface-from-an-external-assembly-thats-marked-as-internal-c)

Comment: Try using *Reflection* if you can't modify the assembly

Comment: There is a difference between an assembly and an interface @PeterDuniho

Comment: It's true there's a difference between an assembly and an interface. So? The _approved_ way to gain access to an assembly's contents that are marked `internal`, whether interfaces (as in the other question) or a static method in a class (as in your question) is to use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`. Frankly, there are probably _dozens_ of questions of which yours is a duplicate; I just picked the oldest one that was directly applicable (i.e. which had an answer that is exactly the same as the one you need here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Assembly A, you could add the InternalsVisibleTo attribute:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You should of course consider just making it public if it is something to be used in other assemblies.